# f# convert seq obj to seq records

Tags: f#

I am trying to read data from database and convert them to seq of records.
When executing

```
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.SqlClient


type foo = {name:int; author:int}

[<Literal>]
let query = "Select * from Authors"

[<Literal>]//DESKTOP-5RIV0K1
let connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-5RIV0K1;Initial Catalog=TestBase;Integrated Security=True"

let cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<query,connectionString>(connectionString)

let result = cmd.Execute() |> printfn "%A"

result
```

I get

```
seq
  [{ AuthorID = 1; Name = Some "2" }; { AuthorID = 2; Name = Some "3" };
   { AuthorID = 3; Name = Some "4" }]
```

But when I am trying to convert seq obj to seq foo with code below

```
let result = 
    for item in cmd.Execute() do
    match item.Name, item.AuthorID with
        | Some itemName, Some itemAuthor ->
            {name = itemName; author = Some itemAuthor }
        | _ -> ()
```

I get error

> Some itemAuthor
>
> Error FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
>       'int'     but here has type
>       ''a option'

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match records that look like this...

```
{ AuthorID = 1; Name = Some "2" }
```

...using a pattern that looks like this...

```
| Some itemName, Some itemAuthor ->
```

Notice that your AuthorID is an integer. It is not an `Option<int>`. Consequently, the pattern with two Some values is not compatible. You should have a pattern like this instead...

```
| Some itemName, itemAuthor ->
```